# wrong to use a deconstructor?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, finalizer

I have some files written to a temp location in c#. They are then rendered as pdf thumbnails. When the object is destroyed i want the location cleaned up so is it ok in this instance to use a deconstructor?

```
    ~Foo()
    {
        try
        {
            Directory.Delete(path, true);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("exception: " + ex.Message + " . from: Foo_Closing");
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

Even though it has the same syntax as a C++ destructor this a **finalizer** in C# which runs when the object is garbage collected at finalization - this will have a performance impact since the GC has to run a separate thread to run all finalizers, to do this your object instance will live longer than neccessary.

Having said that you should not use it if you do not absolutely have to - an exception is when you have to dispose of resources, in which case your class should also implement `IDisposable`. This would allow consumers of your class to wrap it in a `using` block, which will call `Dispose()` - that is where you should tear down resources.

Comment: the above wasnt meant rudley btw :) you just told me what i shouldnt do at the time .

Comment: @ricki: Understood - I added to my answer: Implement `IDisposable` and dispose of resources there - use a `using` block when instantiating your class, also call `Dispose()` in your finalizer. If possible delete temp folder earlier or use system temp folder

Answer (score 3):

You should implement the IDisposable interface, and do your cleanup in there.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with deconstructors (aka destructors or finalizers) is that you can't predict when they will run, since they are called by the garbage collector. In order to have a predictable behavior, you should implement `IDisposable` and call `Dispose` explicitly (or use the object in a `using` block)

You can also call `Dispose` from the destructor in case it was not called explicitly. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx) for the recommended pattern to use.

Comment: +1 for using - probably worth pointing out that implementing IDisposable properly can be slightly tricky and that disposable members mean the containing class needs to be disposable (which makes disposable members a bit of a headache)

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably just use the environment's temporary file/folder locations so that the files can be cleaned up by a user or administrator as part of the normal housekeeping process.

Don't bother doing this as it smacks of a hack - is it really that important that the folders are deleted there and then?

Comment: yes because - for a particular search i only want the returned pdfs displayed, if i wait for a user to clean up then the folder will be populated with old contents and new

Comment: Could you clean up the folder _before_ you make a search?

Answer (score 2):

Avoid implementing finalzers of at all possible. You don't control when they get called, and they cause performance loss as the runtime needs to treat objects with finalizers specially. In general, you should only implement a finalizer if you have a native object handle or other native resource that needs to be cleaned up.

Instead, implement the IDisposable interface on your class, move your cleanup code to the Dispose method, and make sure all your clients call the Dispose method (the `using` statement is handy for this purpose).

Answer (score 2):

Implement the IDisposable Interface istead:

```
public class tester : IDisposable
{
    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //cleanup code here
    }

    #endregion
}

using (tester t = new tester())
{

}
//tester now disposed
```

But don't forget [this gem of knowledge from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> Because the Dispose method must be
>   called explicitly, objects that
>   implement IDisposable must also
>   implement a finalizer to handle
>   freeing resources when Dispose is not
>   called

So, you should also implement you finalizer as well as your IDisposable interface, bearing in mind that both will be called.

Comment: But the "freeing resources" here refers to native resources, like HANDLEs to opened files and the like, doesn't it? Externalities like files in the file system, which aren't opened in your code, don't apply as "resources" in this context.

Comment: The term "resources" is a bit unclear.  A resource isn't a "thing"--it's a responsibility which only some particular object has the information and impetus to carry out.  The creation of a file which is supposed to be deleted before a program exits is such a responsibility; I'd be a little leery of a little leery of deleting files within a Finalize method (what C# annoyingly calls a "destructor"), though, since various factors may cause such operations to fail or be blocked for an arbitrarily long time.  Note also that finalizers can sometimes run before they're expected to, causing trouble.

Answer (score 1):

why not use IDisposable inteface instead and then you can wrap your call with "using" and  Dispose() will perform all the clean up it needs to perform

`public class Foo : IDisposable`
`{`
`public void Dispose() { //Clean up  here}`
`}`

`using (foo = new Foo() ) { //consume foo here  }`

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to delete temp files on close, if you are able to leverage that it doesn't matter right? Try these links

1. [Handling with temporary file stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519429/handling-with-temporary-file-stream)
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileoptions.aspx
3. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Taking_care_of_temp_files.aspx?msg=3489384