# JSON object does not serialize for huge data

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I am trying to serialize data in JSON. But i face below exception.

> OutOfMemoryException was unhandled by user code.
>   An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Below i defined my code:

**Main controller:**

```
public class TrackingController : BaseAngularController
{
    var lstDetails = _services.GetTrackingDetailsByAWBIds(awbids, awbType);
    if (lstDetails != null)
    {
        return AngularJson(lstDetails);
    }
}
```

**Base Controller:**

```
public abstract class BaseAngularController : Controller
{
    public AngularJsonResult<T> AngularJson<T>(T model)
    {
        return new AngularJsonResult<T>() { Data = model };
    }
}
```

**Angular JSON Result class:**

```
public class AngularJsonResult<T> :AngularJsonResult
{
    public new T Data
    {
        get { return (T)base.Data; }
        set { base.Data = value; }
    }
}
```

**JSON Result class:**

```
public class AngularJsonResult : JsonResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        DoUninterestingBaseClassStuff(context);

        SerializeData(context.HttpContext.Response);
    }

    private void DoUninterestingBaseClassStuff(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType) ? "application/json" : ContentType;

        if (ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SerializeData(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        if (ErrorMessages.Any())
        {
            Data = new
            {
                ErrorMessage = string.Join("\n", ErrorMessages),
                ErrorMessages = ErrorMessages.ToArray()
            };

            response.StatusCode = 400;
        }

        if (Data == null) return;

        response.Write(Data.ToJson());
    }
}
```

**Serializing Object to JSON:**

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static string ToJson<T>(this T obj, bool includeNull = true)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new StringEnumConverter() },
            ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,//newly added
            //PreserveReferencesHandling =Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
            NullValueHandling = includeNull ? NullValueHandling.Include : NullValueHandling.Ignore
        };
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
    }
}
```

Here i defined `AngularJson` method for passing object and override `ExecuteResult` method for converting Object to JSON.

So my `SerializeData` method was passing `Response` and converting to Objet in JSON, like `Data.ToJson()`

Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: Is this code deployed, on a test server, or are you testing it through an IDE? What IDE are you using?

Comment: Yes this code deployed on test server.

Comment: So this might be a JVM memory problem - this sounds like you haven't allocated enough memory to handle whatever it is you're trying to serialize. How large is the data?

Comment: how i can allocated memory... i am not able to find size of the data... its combination of more than 7 database tables.

Comment: If this is a managed server (internal) you should contact your IT helpdesk and talk to them about the service container you're using. Are you using Tomcat? Glassfish?

Comment: What is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the message, exception type. **traceback** and inner exception, if any?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are serializing your *huge data* to a string in memory on the server, then writing the entire string to the `HttpResponseBase` (which also buffers everything by default), and running out of memory somewhere in the process, possibly by exceeding the [maximum c# string length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string).

One way to reduce memory use is to serialize directly to [`HttpResponseBase.OutputStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponsebase.outputstream.aspx) using [`JsonSerializer.Serialize()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Serialize_2.htm).  This avoids the intermediate string representation.

You *may* also need to set [`HttpResponseBase.Buffer = false`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponsebase.buffer.aspx), and if so, follow the advice given in [Unbuffered Output Very Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010915/unbuffered-output-very-slow) and wrap the output stream in a `BufferedStream`.

The following extension method can be used for this:

```
public static class HttpResponseBaseExtensions
{
    public static void WriteJson<T>(this HttpResponseBase response, T obj, bool useResponseBuffering = true, bool includeNull = true)
    {
        var contentEncoding = response.ContentEncoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;
        if (!useResponseBuffering)
        {
            response.Buffer = false;

            // use a BufferedStream as suggested in //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010915/unbuffered-output-very-slow
            var bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(response.OutputStream, 256 * 1024);
            bufferedStream.WriteJson(obj, contentEncoding, includeNull);
            bufferedStream.Flush();
        }
        else
        {
            response.OutputStream.WriteJson(obj, contentEncoding, includeNull);
        }
    }

    static void WriteJson<T>(this Stream stream, T obj, Encoding contentEncoding, bool includeNull)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new StringEnumConverter() },
            ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,//newly added
            //PreserveReferencesHandling =Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
            NullValueHandling = includeNull ? NullValueHandling.Include : NullValueHandling.Ignore
        };
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
        var textWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, contentEncoding);
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, obj);
        textWriter.Flush();
    }
}
```

Then use the extension method in place of `response.Write(Data.ToJson());`