# ASP.NET MVC- Slow download from my website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download

My website has download functionality. When I download any file from it, the browser shows speed around 250 KBPS. whereas if I download from some other website and look at the speed, it is around 900 to 1200 KBPS. I have tested my application in multiple servers and it gives relatively less downloading speed.

Following is the sample code that I use for downloading to client.

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    //Code to form the file path.
    return File(filePath, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

I have also tried sending the file as chunks in my response and the speed is still the same.

What is the reason for such a difference in downloading speed? Is there anything that I can check in my Web.config or IIS settings?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010915/unbuffered-output-very-slow/26023967#26023967

Comment: Where is your server hosted?

Comment: Its in Houston.. How does that make a huge difference in speed?

Comment: What I meant was, is it hosted at a hosting provider?  Or are you running it on your home computer?  Download speed is often a function of the speed of the outbound connection.  So if your server is not hosted somewhere with a very fast outbound speed, it will be slower than when you access other sites that have better outbound speeds.